# Vuetify - How Reduce Button Radius?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I'm trying to reduce the clickable area of a button in my vuetify 3 app-bar.

Currently the button looks like this: [image: Button]

Whereby I'd rather not have all the white space around it (the light blue part you see). So the only clickable part should be in the text, thus reducing the space the button occupies.

I'm not quite sure how to achieve this, I've read their documentation and it appears like I might have to change up some SASS variables, but nothing I tried so far worked. Would really appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

```
        <v-btn @click="" color="blue" text>How it works</v-btn>
```

Comment: which version of Vuetify you are on?

Comment: @NehaSoni Vuetify 3

Comment: Okay, the `text` prop is not available in Vuetify 3, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the `width` or `min-width` prop of `v-button`. Another option is to set a custom CSS class on the button which overrides the CSS `min-width` rule of the button.